# What happens when pressing either L1 or R1 when located on the Home Screen of the PlayStation 4?

Tags: ps4

When located on the main Home Screen for the PlayStation 4, I've noticed that pressing either L1 or R1 on the DualShock 4 remote appears to perform some kind of action related to the menu. I'm totally blind, so can't easily tell what happens when either of these buttons are pressed - would somebody be able to explain which menu/function is activated when either of these buttons are pressed on the Home Screen?

Comment: Thank you for testing - out of interest, does either R1 or L1 do anything for you?

Comment: L1 moves to the beginning of horizontal lists and R1 to the end.

Comment: Apologies - it appears that these were actually the buttons that performed the action that I noticed. Feel free to list these as an answer and I'll accept. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

L1 moves to the beginning of horizontal lists and R1 to the end.

L2 and R2 don't seem to do anything.